# How do you use elif when defining a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to execute code like the following

```
y = 6
x = 7 if y/6 == 1 elif y/6 == 2 x = 5 else x = 4
```

Simply, it does not work. I'm not sure how to make elif statements fit into defining variables on one line.

I'm able to use else statements like the following

```
y = 6
x = 7 if y/6 == 1 else x = 4
```

I want to be able to set x to 7 if y/6 ==1, x to 5 if y/6 == 2 and x to 4 if neither of those are the case

Comment: Why does it need to be on one line to begin with? It’s incomprehensible, even if it worked.

Comment: I don't think `elif` is supported in ternary expressions. You can chain with `a if b else c if d else e`

Answer (score 1):

Use chained ternary expressions:

```
>>> y = 6
>>> x = 7 if y/6 == 1 else 5 if y/6 == 2 else 4
>>> x
7
```

The way to read this is:

```
x = ((7) if y/6 == 1 else ((5) if y/6 == 2 else (4)))
```

i.e. each `expr1 if pred else expr2` is itself an expression.

Comment: I didnt know there was a way to technically work elif into a ternary expression, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You only need `x = ...` once at the beginning.  The rest of the expression is evaluated as a value that will be assigned to x.  You don't need to mention `x` again.

```
x = 7 if y/6 == 1 else 5 if y/6 == 2 else 4
```

In general, the syntax is

```
var = value1 if condition1 else value2 if condition2 else value3
```